# INDEX , MATCH issue where return value never comes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using the following formula:

`=INDEX(array, MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, 0))`

Exactly it looks like:

`=INDEX('Sheet B'!B:B, MATCH(E2, 'Sheet B'!X:X, 0))`

The problem is it works for all cases where cells in Column X have only the lookup_value. 
I need a formula that will consider it a match if it finds this exact 13 character value but also contains other text.

Example:

**Works**

lookup_value=CVE-2007-1205

cell in column X=CVE-2007-1205

**Doesn't work**

lookup_value=CVE-2007-1205

cell in column X=CVE-2007-1205, 2007-A-0020

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
=INDEX('Sheet'!B:B, MATCH("*" & E2 & "*", 'Sheet'!X:X, 0))
```

Comment: If you want to regain control of your question you can register an account and then request to have your accounts merged. Then you can go to https://superuser.com/contact selecting "I need to merge accounts" and enter the old and new account links. For your information your two accounts are https://superuser.com/users/707339/user707339 and https://superuser.com/users/707320/user707320